# Remove vertex from GLBuffer

Tags: ios, opengl-es

If I'm adding vertexes to an array buffer as below, how would I delete the last vertex added?

```
// Append vertex to array buffer
static inline void addVertex(NSUInteger *length, NISignaturePoint v) {
    if ((*length) >= maxLength) {
        return;
    }

    GLvoid *data = glMapBufferOES(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY_OES);
    memcpy(data + sizeof(NISignaturePoint) * (*length), &v, sizeof(NISignaturePoint));
    glUnmapBufferOES(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);

    (*length)++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That't not how OpenGL Buffer Objects work. glMapBuffer{OES} gives you a mapping of fast memory of a certain size, that has been defined when initializing the buffer object with glBufferData{OES}. You can't just write beyond the limits of that object or mapping and expect data to be appended. You you need to resize the buffer object you need to reinitialize it.

Also OpenGL does not organize Buffer Objects in entities of "vertices". It's just formless data, which you have to fill with meaning (be making apropriate calls to glVertexAttribPointer & Co.).

Your code is so wrong, due to misconception of how OpenGL{-ES} works, that it can not even be fixed.